# How to decompose a unknown transformation matrix?

Tags: math, matrix, directx

I'm working in the revitalization of an old 3d game (built using Direct3D) and I'm struggling with the game objects animations.

The game has its objects animations stored in binary files that contains transformation matrices for each bone of its meshes at each frame of the animation (in the form of an array of `D3DMATRIX`).

I've tried using the `D3DXMatrixDecompose` function to get the position, rotation and scale but it seems that something is wrong with the animation. Some animations almost matches the originals, but there are some strange rotations in the middle of the animations (the scale vector goes from negative to positive values and that causes the whole bone to rotate in an strange way - it is definitely wrong) and for other animations the whole thing is wrong.

I read somewhere that the function `D3DXMatrixDecompose` assumes the matrix was composed as a SRT matrix and apparently the order in which each component was combined in the matrix matters. So, as the animations are clearly wrong I'm assuming maybe the matrices were not composed in the SRT order and the output of `D3DXMatrixDecompose` is wrong.

I didn't find much material to read about this without going very deep on math. As I don't have a strong background on math, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

So, how can I decompose position, rotation and scale of an unknown transformation matrix? I'm not asking for a unique algorithm that can do that, I'm asking what I can do in this scenario to find the original (or equivalents) values for the position, rotation and scale of each matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to read some math... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati and this for rotation matrix -> quaternion for example: https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of ``XMMatrixDecompose`` in [DirectXMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/master/Inc/DirectXMathMatrix.inl)